# Is there a better way to look if a string is contained in a different lists of strings?

Tags: python, list, mapping

I have a string called "block", and I want to check in which list it is contained. It works for me as below, but I was wondering if there is a better way (maybe a mapper or dict key\value or something similar). This is what I have:

```
def get_block_container(block: str) -> str:

    if block in ['sss', 'srs']:
        return 'prime'
    if block in ['aaa', 'aba']:
        return 'general'
    if block in ['kkk', 'klk']:
        return 'alpha'
    if block in ['zyz', 'zzz']:
        return 'beta'
    return ''
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? as the list may go longer with time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach has a complexity of `O(n*m)` (where `n` is the number of branches and `m` the length of the longest list) I'd use a dictionary which will allow for a `O(1)` lookup:

```py
def get_block_container(block: str) -> str:
    return {
        'sss': 'prime',
        'srs': 'prime',
        'aaa': 'general',
        'aba': 'general',
        'kkk': 'alpha',
        'klk': 'alpha',
        'zyz': 'beta',
        'zzz': 'beta'
    }.get(block, '')
```

This can be improved more by defining the dictionary as a const outside of the function (so it doesn't need to be created every time the function is called) and by using consts/enum for the values so there is less repetition, for example:

```py
...

BLOCK_CONTAINER_MAPPING = {
        'sss': 'prime',
        'srs': 'prime',
        'aaa': 'general',
        'aba': 'general',
        'kkk': 'alpha',
        'klk': 'alpha',
        'zyz': 'beta',
        'zzz': 'beta'
    }

...

def get_block_container(block: str) -> str:
    return BLOCK_CONTAINER_MAPPING.get(block, '')
```

Comment: You completely disregarding the list of strings here. I don't think this is what he asked for.

Comment: @rafathasan This and OP's code have the exact same output for the same inputs. It does not disregard anything

Comment: @rafathasan - No, the strings are all there. All OP is trying to do is map a string contained in a list into another string. Here, each list is exploded into the keys of the dictionary with the proper mapping to the associated value.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a dictionary that has the mapping of strings such as

```
example_dict = {
"sss" : "prime" # So the value of sss will be prime
"srs" : "prime"  # So the value of srs will be prime
"aaa" : "general"  # So the value of aaa will be general
"aba" : "general"  # So the value of aba will be general
#...
}
```

then you can use dictionaries `get()` method to find out the value of block.

Comment: But this would require defining variables `sss = "sss"` and etc... Better to just use the strings themselves in the dict definition.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name. It overwrites the builtin.

Comment: I wrote it just as an example. However, thanks for the information.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the return values in a `dict` as keys and return them like this:

```
def get_block_container(block: str) -> str:

    dict_list = {"prime": ['sss', 'srs'], "general": ['aaa', 'aba'], "alpha": ['zyz', 'zzz']}

    for key in dict_list:
        if block in dict_list[key]
            return key
```

Comment: This doesn't improve the complexity at all. Using a dict then iterating its values removes any benefit the dict has provided

Comment: @DeepSpace Please the question. There is nothing about complexity at all.

Comment: OP asks for a "better way". Better complexity undoubtedly counts for "better way".

Comment: @DeepSpace OP says _I was wondering if there is a better way_ so mentioning complexity is well in bounds. This is is not as good of a solution as just mapping keys to values.

Comment: "Is there a simpler way to do it?"

Comment: @rafathasan - Right! This not the simpler way. There is a very clear cut way to do this mapping. Your solution is not that way.